# C#, ASP.NET - Gathering data from a database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sdk

I have code, which returns me a row out of a database,

```
            con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();
            dsl = new DataSet();
            con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\\tbl.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";

            con.Open();

            string sql = "SELECT * From tbl_fb";
            da = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);
            da.Fill(dsl, "fb");
            DataRow dRow = dsl.Tables["fb"].Rows[0];
            ViewData["a"] = dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(1).ToString();

            ViewData["b"] = "afagjma";
            con.Close();
```

Is there a way, that I could use a loop to get all rows from table. The number of rows are unknown.
I know I can do it with a loop, by using the variable (i) instead of numbers. But then I would need to use the `ViewData` array, which is problem for me.

Example: ViewData["a"][i];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set up a class that defines what data you're returning from your database.

For instance:

```
public class Customer  
{
   public int Id { get; set;} 
   public string Name { get; set;} 
}
```

And then you would create a `List<Customer>()`, and set this as the Model for your MVC Page.

For instance:

```
var data = new new List<Customer>();    
ViewData.Model = data;
```

And load your data into your list:

```
foreach(var row in dsl.Tables["fb"].Rows)
{
   var customer = new Customer(); 
   customer.Id = row.Field<int?>("Id"); 
   customer.Name = row.Field<string>("Name");
   data.Add(customer);
}
```

And then, on your MVC Page, set the `<%@ Page %>` header to have the Inherits attribute like so:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<Customer>>" %>
```

Now finally you can bind directly to the Model within the page:

```
<% foreach (var item in Model) { %>
  Customer Id: <%: item.Id %>
  Name: <%: item.Name %>
<% } %>
```

Comment: Thanks man. I first started trying out your code. So i ran to a problem. The program underlines me a .Field<...>()
I have system.data included. Any info why its returning that error?

Comment: You need to reference System.Data.DatasetExtensions (took me a bit to find that, heh)

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to go through each DataRow in your "fb" table is:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dsl.Tables["fb"].Rows) {
    // do something with each row
}
```

This will run through all rows of your table.

To return a value of a particular column in your DataRow object, do something like this:

```
string firstName = (string)dr["FirstName"];
string lastName = (string)dr["LastName"];
int age = (int)dr["Age"];
```

By doing this, you're saying "Get me the value from the 'FirstName' column and cast it as an string, cast the value from the 'Age' column as an integer, and so-on.  However you need to verify the type being returned for each column and adjust your casts accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop through `dsl` as this is the dataset.  This is your problem:

```
DataRow dRow = dsl.Tables["fb"].Rows[0];
```

You are getting a single DataRow `Rows[0]` where you need to loop through `dsl` to get **each and every** `DataRow`

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a `DataReader` instead? It would work in a loop reading one row at a time. You can use it to populate a `DataTable` and pass it on to a `DataSet`, if needed.